# Need to change image to green for specific time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to set interval time to show my red button to green and then again to red.

I have 5 text box where one text box is defining the sequence that which button will 1st set to green. I have tried bellow thing but all button gets change to red with out time interval.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>signal</h2>

 sequence : <input type="text" id="txtsequence1" value="1,3,2,4" /><br /> 
 signal 1 :<input type="text" id="txt1" value="5" /><br /> 
 signal 2 :<input type="text" id="txt2" value="2" /><br /> 
 signal 3 :<input type="text" id="txt3" value="6" /><br /> 
 signal 4:<input type="text" id="txt4" value="7" /><br />


<input type="button" onclick="return start()" value="Submit" />
<br />
<img class="abc" src="~/Images/red.jpg" style="height:25px;width:25px" id="image1" alt="img1">
<img class="abc" src="~/Images/red.jpg" style="height:25px;width:25px" id="image2" alt="img2">
<img class="abc" src="~/Images/red.jpg" style="height:25px;width:25px" id="image3" alt="img3">
<img class="abc" src="~/Images/red.jpg" style="height:25px;width:25px" id="image4" alt="img4">

<script>
  function start() {
    var value = document.getElementById("txtsequence1").value;
    var spit = value.split(",");
    for (var i = 1; i <= spit.length; i++) {
      var interval = document.getElementById("txt" + i).value * 1000;
      var images = document.getElementById("image" + i);
      images.src = "/Images/green.jpg";
      setInterval(changegred, interval);
    }

    function changegred() {
      $(".abc").attr("src", "/Images/red.jpg")
    }
  }
</script>
```

What I want that in seq table it is define as 1,3,2,4
and in other text box the time interval for 1 image is set as 5

1. Now for 1 image time interval is set as 5 so the 1 image will change red image to green for 5 second
2. Now for 3 image time interval is set as 6 so the 1 image will change to red and 3 image will set as green
3. now in 2 image time interval is set as 2 so the 3 image will change to red and 2 image will set as green
4. now in 4 image time interval is set as 7 so the 2 image will change to red and 4 image will set as green

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you want to do correctly, this should do the trick.

I'm using colored divs instead of images, but that shouldn't matter.

The idea here is that we precompute the actions we want to take into an array, and then walk through that with a function and setTimeout.

```js
var actions = [];
var actionTimer = null;

function resetLights() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".abc")).forEach(el => el.classList.remove("green"));
}


function playNextAction() {
  if (!actions.length) {  // nothing to do?
    resetLights();  // reset, then quit.
    return;
  }
  var action = actions.shift(); // take the first action
  resetLights(); // reset all lights
  action.element.classList.add("green"); // set the current light to green
  actionTimer = setTimeout(playNextAction, action.interval); // enqueue next action in interval
}

function start() {
  var value = document.getElementById("txtsequence1").value;
  actions = value.split(",").map((i) => {
    var interval = document.getElementById("txt" + i).value * 1000;
    var element = document.getElementById("image" + i);
    return {
      element,
      interval
    };
  });
  clearTimeout(actionTimer); // clear any pending action
  playNextAction(); // play next action
}
```

```css
.abc {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

.abc.green {
  background: lime;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h2>signal</h2>

 sequence : <input type="text" id="txtsequence1" value="1,3,2,4" /><br /> 
 signal 1 : <input type="number" id="txt1" value="5" /><br /> 
 signal 2 : <input type="number" id="txt2" value="2" /><br /> 
 signal 3 : <input type="number" id="txt3" value="6" /><br /> 
 signal 4 : <input type="number" id="txt4" value="7" /><br />


<input type="button" onclick="return start()" value="Submit" />
<br />
<div class="abc" id="image1" alt="img1">1</div>
<div class="abc" id="image2" alt="img2">2</div>
<div class="abc" id="image3" alt="img3">3</div>
<div class="abc" id="image4" alt="img4">4</div>
```

Comment: it is not staying for 5 second on image1 and also at last the 4 should also get convert to red

Comment: @miteshjain Fixed. In my impatience, I had 100ms as the multiplier, not 1000. Added the reset too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>signal</h2>

sequence : <input type="text" id="txtsequence1" value="1,3,2,4" /><br />
signal 1 :<input type="text" id="txt1" value="5" /><br />
signal 2 :<input type="text" id="txt2" value="2" /><br />
signal 3 :<input type="text" id="txt3" value="6" /><br />
signal 4:<input type="text" id="txt4" value="7" /><br />


<input type="button" onclick="return start()" value="Submit" />
<br />
<img class="abc" src="~/Images/red.jpg" style="height:25px;width:25px" id="image1" alt="">
<img class="abc" src="~/Images/red.jpg" style="height:25px;width:25px" id="image2" alt="">
<img class="abc" src="~/Images/red.jpg" style="height:25px;width:25px" id="image3" alt="">
<img class="abc" src="~/Images/red.jpg" style="height:25px;width:25px" id="image4" alt="">

<script>
    var count = 0;
    function start() {

        var value = document.getElementById("txtsequence1").value;
        var spit = value.split(",");
        var intervalUpto = 0;

        for (var i = 1; i <= spit.length; i++) {
            count = spit[i - 1];
            var intervalCurrent = document.getElementById("txt" + count).value * 1000;           
            var b = createInterval(funcb, count, intervalUpto);
            createInterval(clearInterval, b, intervalUpto);
            intervalUpto = intervalUpto + intervalCurrent;
            var a = createInterval(funca, count, intervalUpto);
            createInterval(clearInterval, a, intervalUpto);
        }

        function funca(id) {
            var images = document.getElementById("image" + id);
            images.src = "/Images/red.jpg";
        }

        function funcb(id) {
            var images = document.getElementById("image" + id);
            images.src = "/Images/green.jpg";
        }
        function clearInterval(id) { clearTimeout(id); }

        function createInterval(f, dynamicParameter, interval) { return setInterval(function () { f(dynamicParameter); }, interval); }
    }
</script>
```

Here I had also resolved this in some different way